# Optical Atom Trapping

Tags: optics

I have asked a similar question in relation to this topic, although I have been reading up on optical trapping some more and have many more questions. One question, in particular, is in relation to 'blue box' traps, as mentioned in this report here; [Link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.09716.pdf)

In this report and other similar reports I have read, the atoms are always cooled down to nK temperatures. I have read that this is not a necessary part of the trapping process, but instead done to allow for more accurate measurement results, is this true?

Can this type of optical trapping allow for neutral atoms to be at temperatures close to room temp ( ie 200-300 K) while still allowing them to "freely" move?

Comment: Hi @Jagerber48, I hope you don't mind viewing this question, as you helped me a lot previously, with a similar question. Thanks.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with particle physics .